# Image upload appearing as broken images following server move

Tags: images, database, uploads

I've got the horrible task of moving a site from one hosting server to another and had no end of problems for DNS issues to temporary domain issues and FTP issues.

However I've managed to install a new database and import the backup of the old wordpress site and all is looking fine - I've got everything hidden behind a holding page (script in the wp-blog-header.php file allows access only to logged in users) and testing things out.

First issue I came across was the WYSIWYG editor was missing all the buttons for styling etc - so I re-uploaded all the wp files again and that solved the matter.

Second issue is that when writing a post and uploading an image, the image uploads but doesn't appear - there is no thumbnail appearing afte crunching and if I click to insert image into post I just get a blank box with a broken file link icon in it. I checked to the uploads folder and the image has uploaded and crumched just fine - so don't understand why it's not appearing in the blog post.

Any ideas of how to resolve this?

Thanks

E

Answer (score 1):

Moving is a royal pain indeed and everything goes into the details. A possible solution to these potential problems is a new plugin that was just released, it's called the Duplicator: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/duplicator/
I haven't tested it yet, just saw the news in my Reader, but saw the video and it looks pretty awesome.
So you can basically delete all your previous work, go back to the old site, run the duplicator, install the package on the new site and it all should be there.
Let me know if it works for you.!

Comment: no thanks... I just want to fix the problem I have at the moment and not start from scratch.

Comment: Thank you for that tip. I am looking desperately for a comfortable solution.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that moving a WP installation from one server to another is messy, with lots of manual fixing required.

1. At risk of stating the obvious, make sure all your wordpress settings are correct for the new server/url.
2. Edit the database directly (are you familiar with how to do that?), find and update all references to the old server or server-specific file paths. Last time I did this, there were about 8 separate values that I had to update manually.

Even if your installation isn't working properly right now, I'd still take a backup of the database before doing any of this.

Let me know how you get on,

Philip

Comment: I had a root around and thought it might have something to do with permissions on folder and files, so I changed the permissions on the uploads folder and the folders within that to 755 and that fixed the issue - they were all set to 711.